Web3 Rpc Call Error on Next Js Server Call with Cloudflare
We have a project that use viem (similar to ethers js) and next js App to simplify.
The issue what we are having is only in production.

"ContractFunctionExecutionError: HTTP request failed.\n\nURL: https://bartio.rpc.berachain.com/nRequest body: {"method":"eth_call","params":[{"data":"0x9980a3a10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017","to":"0x2ac86f64936a999275eE4Cf1979c6626B361175b"},"latest"]}\n \nRaw Call Arguments:\n to: 0x2ac86f64936a999275eE4Cf1979c6626B361175b\n data: 0x9980a3a10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017\n \nContract Call:\n address: 0x2ac86f64936a999275eE4Cf1979c6626B361175b\n function: getTools(uint256 tokenId)\n args: (23)\n\nDocs: https://viem.sh/docs/contract/readContract/nDetails: XMLHttpRequest is not defined\nVersion: 2.20.1"

This happend on the Server Call
const getStoreData = async () => {
  const tokenId = getTokenId()

  if (!tokenId) return DEFAULT_STORE

  const tools = await getTools(tokenId)
  const toolsUpgrades = await getUpgrades(tokenId)

  return { tools, toolsUpgrades }
}

interface StoreProps {
  toolCapacity: bigint
}

export default async function Store({ toolCapacity }: StoreProps) {
  const { tools, toolsUpgrades } = await getStoreData()

The pages run with the EDGE runtime because that is how cloudflare required to setup. Here is the web3 Method (I have others calls that neither works also)
export const getTools = async (tokenId: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await publicClient.readContract({
      address: CONTRACTS.multicall,
      abi: multicallABI,
      functionName: 'getTools',
      args: [BigInt(tokenId)],
    })

    const formattedResponse: ToolState[] = response.map((tool) => ({
      id: tool.id.toString(),
      amount: tool.amount.toString(),
      cost: formatEther(tool.cost),
      ups: formatEther(tool.ups),
      upsTotal: formatEther(tool.upsTotal),
      percentOfProduction: Number(formatEther(tool.percentOfProduction)).toFixed(2),
      maxed: Boolean(tool.maxed),
    }))

    const lastItem = formattedResponse.findLast((item) => +item.amount > 0)

    if (lastItem) {
      const lastItemIndex = formattedResponse.findIndex((item) => item.id === lastItem.id)
      const list = formattedResponse.slice(0, lastItemIndex + 4)

      return list
    }

    return formattedResponse.slice(0, 3)
  } catch (error) {
    logger('getTools()', error)

    return []
  }
}

We try modifying the ways we call the rpc, change it the rpc_url and we are still having the error.
We don't want to do the call on the client side.
What I try was deploy on Vercel and there is working correctly. So my conclusion is a config on cloudflare that is missing.
SOLUTION:
We modify the next config. The Viem library seems to use cross-fetch that doesn't like it cloudflare.
const nextConfig = {

logging: {
fetches: {
fullUrl: true,
},
},
webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
if (isServer) {
  config.resolve.alias['cross-fetch'] = 'node-fetch'
}

return config

},
}
